# Construct PHP associative array from two SQL tables

Tags: php, json, postgresql

I am using PHP to construct the following PostgreSQL query

`$sql = 'SELECT * FROM acs_14_5yr_2p05_senate;`

With the following While loop:

```
$rs = $conn->query($sql);
$acsjson = array('ACS'  => array());
while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $properties = $row;
    $feature = array(
        'geographicProfile' => $properties
    );
    array_push($acsjson['ACS'], $feature);
}

echo json_encode($acsjson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Which returns the following JSON:

```
{"ACS":[
    {"geographicProfile":{
        "senateid":"610U400US27001",
        "geo_display":"State Senate District 01",
        "hc01_vc03":32525,
        "hc01_vc04":21032,
        "hc01_vc05":8869,
        "hc01_vc06":16853,
        "hc01_vc07":6042
    }},
    {"geographicProfile":{
        "senateid":"610U400US27002",
        "geo_display":"State Senate District 02",
        "hc01_vc03":31319,
        "hc01_vc04":22041,
        "hc01_vc05":8539,
        "hc01_vc06":17100,
        "hc01_vc07":5666
    }},
    {etc}, {etc}, {etc}
]}
```

The keys in "geographicProfile" are cryptic Census field names. Fortunately they have a separate metadata table where the following query with a similar while loop:

`$metasql = 'SELECT name, description FROM acs_14_5yr_senate_metadata';`

returns

```
 {"metadata":[{"name":"hc01_vc03","description":"Estimate; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households"},
    {"name":"hc02_vc03","description":"Margin of Error; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households"},
    {"name":"hc03_vc03","description":"Percent; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households"},
    {"name":"hc04_vc03","description":"Percent Margin of Error; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households"}, 
    {etc}, {etc}]}
```

I would like to return the original query, with the cryptic Census names associated with its corresponding metadata value in a nested JSON object like this to reveal the value and metadata description of the "hc01_vcXX" fields:

```
{"ACS":[
    {"geographicProfile":{
       "senateid":"610U400US27001",
       "geo_display":"State Senate District 01",
       "hc01_vc03":[32525, metadataQuery['hc01_vc03']]
       "hc01_vc04":[21032, metadataQuery['hc01_vc04']]
       "hc01_vc05":[8869, metadataQuery['hc01_vc05']]
       "hc01_vc06":[16853, metadataQuery['hc01_vc06']]
       "hc01_vc07":[6042, metadataQuery['hc01_vc07']]
    }},
    {"geographicProfile":{
        "senateid":"610U400US27002",
        "geo_display":"State Senate District 02",
        "hc01_vc03":[31319, OtherQuery['hc01_vc03']]
        "hc01_vc04":[22041, OtherQuery['hc01_vc04']]
        "hc01_vc05":[8539, OtherQuery['hc01_vc05']]
        "hc01_vc06":[17100, OtherQuery['hc01_vc06']]
        "hc01_vc07":[5666, OtherQuery['hc01_vc07']]
    }}
    {etc},{etc}
]}
```

Can someone please help me construct the PHP associative array while loop, or offer an alternative solution to my problem? I rarely write any PHP except to create little services like this.

Comment: What's the point of `array_push($acsjson['ACS']);`? you have no value to push.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html

Comment: I think the join will probably work for me. @MarcB I think that was just garbage left over from previous script... I'll make the edit

Comment: @abraCadaver I have looked at joining, however, the metadata table has the "hc01_xx" as rows in the table where the "senate" table has the "hc01_xx" as columns in that table.  And I used "*" as an example in the first query, there are no columns that correspond to the metadata table. So maybe I have to use a pivot?