# Construct nested PHP associative array from a data table and pivoted lookup table

Tags: php, postgresql

I have the following Census data table:

```
| district | hc01_vc03 | hc02_vc03 | hc03_vc03 | hc04_vc03 |
|----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|  01A     |  16681    |    209    |   16681   |   (x)     |
|  01B     |  15844    |    256    |   15844   |   (x)     |
|  02A     |  12514    |    283    |   15214   |   (x)     |
|  02B     |  16105    |    236    |   16105   |   (x)     |
```

And I have the following "lookup" table:

```
|   NAME    | DESCRIPTION                                                      |
|-----------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| hc01_vc03 | "Estimate; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households"                |
| hc02_vc03 | "Margin of Error; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households"         |
| hc03_vc03 | "Percent; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households"                 |
| hc04_vc03 | "Percent Margin of Error; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households" |
```

**I need to return the following JSON object:**

```
 {"Census":[
    {"geographicProfile":{
       "district":"01A",
       "hc01_vc03":[16681, 'Estimate; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households']
       "hc02_vc03":[209, 'Margin of Error; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households']
       "hc03_vc03":[16681, 'Percent; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households']
       "hc04_vc03":['(x)', 'Percent Margin of Error; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households']
    }},
    {""geographicProfile":{
       "district":"01B",
       "hc01_vc03":[15844, 'Estimate; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households']
       "hc02_vc03":[256, 'Margin of Error; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households']
       "hc03_vc03":[15844, 'Percent; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households']
       "hc04_vc03":['(x)', 'Percent Margin of Error; HOUSEHOLDS BY TYPE - Total households']
    }}
    {etc},{etc}
]}
```

Excluding trivial `Select...From...` I can return each table query as a JSON using this basic loop:

```
$acsjson = array('Census'  => array());
while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $properties = $row;
    $feature = array(
        'geographicProfile' => $properties
    );
    array_push($acsjson['Census'], $feature);
}

echo json_encode($acsjson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Which will return each tables JSON object, respectively, without any join between the data and lookup tables.

But I am struggling to turn the "hc0X_vc03" into an array that includes the 'lookup table' query `description` value into that array. I think I need to pivot the lookup table. Can anyone help construct the JSON object?

This is an extension/revision of [my question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797944/construct-php-associative-array-from-two-sql-tables)

I would be interested in SQL or PHP solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see here is that your lookup keys are column names which makes difficult to think how to join them.
But you only need to have all lookup descriptions as a single row joined to each row of the `census data` table.

**Steps (Bottom to Top)**

- Pivot the lookup table using `MAX()` aggregation. Pivoted lookup table has only one row. Can use crosstab function here via tablefunc extension.
- Cross join with `census data` table.
- Using json [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) assemble a json object for each row.
- Using json [aggregation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) assemble a json array of all rows.
- Add final key to json object.

Here is the query.

```
-- add 'Census' Key to aggregated json
SELECT jsonb_build_object('Census', agg_data) final_json FROM
(
  -- assemble json array
  SELECT jsonb_agg(json_data) agg_data FROM
  (
    -- Assemble json object with each row
    SELECT 
      jsonb_build_object(
        'geographicProfile', jsonb_build_object(
          'district', district, 
          'hc01_vc03', jsonb_build_array(hc01_vc03, hc01_vc03_lu), 
          'hc02_vc03', jsonb_build_array(hc02_vc03, hc02_vc03_lu), 
          'hc03_vc03', jsonb_build_array(hc03_vc03, hc03_vc03_lu), 
          'hc04_vc03', jsonb_build_array(hc04_vc03, hc04_vc03_lu)
    )
  ) json_data
  FROM ( 
    -- Cross Join census data with pivoted lookup table
    SELECT 
      district,
      a.hc01_vc03, b.hc01_vc03 hc01_vc03_lu,
      a.hc02_vc03, b.hc02_vc03 hc02_vc03_lu,
      a.hc03_vc03, b.hc03_vc03 hc03_vc03_lu,
      a.hc04_vc03, b.hc04_vc03 hc04_vc03_lu
    FROM
      public.census_data a, 
      (
      -- Pivot lookup table. Put all values in only one row with keys as column names. Could use tablefunc extension here.
      SELECT 
        MAX (CASE WHEN name = 'hc01_vc03' then description END) hc01_vc03,
        MAX (CASE WHEN name = 'hc02_vc03' then description END) hc02_vc03,
        MAX (CASE WHEN name = 'hc03_vc03' then description END) hc03_vc03,
        MAX (CASE WHEN name = 'hc04_vc03' then description END) hc04_vc03 
      FROM
        public.lookup
      ) b
    ) c
  ) d
) e
```

**PHP Processing**

Remove all select involving json functions if you want to do the json assembling in your php code.

```
    -- Cross Join census data with pivoted lookup table
    SELECT 
      district,
      a.hc01_vc03, b.hc01_vc03 hc01_vc03_lu,
      a.hc02_vc03, b.hc02_vc03 hc02_vc03_lu,
      a.hc03_vc03, b.hc03_vc03 hc03_vc03_lu,
      a.hc04_vc03, b.hc04_vc03 hc04_vc03_lu
    FROM
      public.census_data a, 
      (
      -- Pivot lookup table. Put all values in only one row with keys as column names. Could use tablefunc extension here.
      SELECT 
        MAX (CASE WHEN name = 'hc01_vc03' then description END) hc01_vc03,
        MAX (CASE WHEN name = 'hc02_vc03' then description END) hc02_vc03,
        MAX (CASE WHEN name = 'hc03_vc03' then description END) hc03_vc03,
        MAX (CASE WHEN name = 'hc04_vc03' then description END) hc04_vc03 
      FROM
        public.lookup
      ) b
```

Now you have all the info needed in each row to create the json in PHP loop.

**Crosstab function**

`Tablefunc` extension needs to be installed. 
Use this query instead of the pivoting lookup select.

```
SELECT * 
FROM public.crosstab( 'select ''lu1''::text, * from public.lookup' )
AS ct(lookup_name text,
      hc01_vc03 text, hc02_vc03 text,
      hc03_vc03 text, hc04_vc03 text)
```

**CTEs**

CTEs are more 'readable'.

Here is a CTE version of the query.

```
WITH pivoted_lu AS ( -- put all lookup values in one row (pivot)
      SELECT 
        MAX (CASE WHEN name = 'hc01_vc03' then description END) hc01_vc03,
        MAX (CASE WHEN name = 'hc02_vc03' then description END) hc02_vc03,
        MAX (CASE WHEN name = 'hc03_vc03' then description END) hc03_vc03,
        MAX (CASE WHEN name = 'hc04_vc03' then description END) hc04_vc03 
      FROM
        public.lookup

) 
,full_data AS ( -- cross join with census data to have all lookup names available in all rows
SELECT 
  district,
  a.hc01_vc03, b.hc01_vc03 hc01_vc03_lu,
  a.hc02_vc03, b.hc02_vc03 hc02_vc03_lu,
  a.hc03_vc03, b.hc03_vc03 hc03_vc03_lu,
  a.hc04_vc03, b.hc04_vc03 hc04_vc03_lu
FROM public.census_data a, pivoted_lu b
)
-- stop here and get this recordset (select * from full_data) if you want to assemble json in php code...
-- Why would you do this? Postgres offers terrific json manipulation functions !
,json_data as ( -- convert each row to json
SELECT 
jsonb_build_object(
    'geographicProfile', jsonb_build_object(
        'district', district, 
        'hc01_vc03', jsonb_build_array(hc01_vc03, hc01_vc03_lu), 
        'hc02_vc03', jsonb_build_array(hc02_vc03, hc02_vc03_lu), 
        'hc03_vc03', jsonb_build_array(hc03_vc03, hc03_vc03_lu), 
        'hc04_vc03', jsonb_build_array(hc04_vc03, hc04_vc03_lu)
    )
) json_data
FROM full_data
)
,aggregated_json_data as ( -- agreggate into one json array
select jsonb_agg(json_data) agg_data from json_data
)

select jsonb_build_object('Census', agg_data) final_json from aggregated_json_data
```

Comment: Thanks @cachique, this looks very promising. However, I keep getting `ERROR:  function jsonb_build_array(character varying, text) does not exist` . Does that have something to do with the types of characters getting passed into the build array function? Do I have to cast the text as char var, maybe?

Comment: Which version of postgresql are you running?.  There is a 'no binary' counterpart; `json_build_array`. That's for all jsonb functions. Check the links on json.

Comment: 9.4.6 ... UPDATE: I tried casting as var char and now I get: `function jsonb_build_array(character varying, character varying) does not exist`

Comment: 9.4.6  - It looks like i need to upgrade

Comment: >=9.4 needed for that set of json functions. Look the improved **PHP Processing** section. You should be able to create the json object from that SELECT. No need to update postgresql if you don't want to.

Comment: `jasonb_build_array` and `jasonb_build_object` appeared in 9.5 version. Use `jason_build_array` and `jason_build_object` instead. Argument type is not a problem since these functions take any type as arguments. Hope this corrects the error you are getting.